# reading from multiple lines of a file - scanf in c using Linux cat

Tags: c, linux, scanf

I want to read in a stream-like manner from a log file in Linux command line, where the log file looks like this:

```
=== Start ===
I 322334bbaff, 4
I 322334bba0a, 4
 S ff233400ff, 8
I 000004bbaff, 4
L 322334bba0a, 4
=== End ===
```

and I have a c file to read every line of the `log file` and store the memory address and the size of it (e.g., `322334bba0a` and `4`) in each eligible line.

```
// my_c.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (!isatty(fileno(stdin))) {

    int long long addr; 
    int size; 
    char func;

    while(scanf("%c %llx, %d\n",&func, &addr, &size))
    {
         if(func=='I')
           {
    fprintf(stdout, "%llx ---- %d\n", addr,size);
           }
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Since it should work as a stream, I have to use the pipe:

```
$ cat log 2>&1 | ./my_c
```

`2>&1` is used since the principle process that replaces `cat log` is a program tracing from valgrind tools that is in `stderr`.

`./my_c` only reads the first line of the `log file`. I was hoping to read each line as it comes through the pipe and store the memory address and the size of the line.

I am very new to c programming and have searched a lot for a way to solve this. The current code is what I came up with so far.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you might need to account for the potential leading space.

Comment: Tip: Don't clutter your variable definitions up on one line. It just makes it harder for us to see what's going on.

Comment: I edited the file

Comment: Did you try searching for "How do I write a loop in C?" Although if you don't know the answer, you need to read an introductory text. Neither SO nor internet snippets can give you a foundation.

Comment: @rici Considering the while loop to iteratively scanning for each line. I can't use for loop as the number of lines in log file is in billions. I added the while loop FYI.

Comment: You need to check the value returned by `scanf`.  If the first line of input is `=== Start ===`, then I would expect `scanf("%c %llx, %d\n",&func, &addr, &size)` to match only one conversion specifier on the first call.  It will consume one `=`.  The second call will consume the next `=`.

Comment: Read a line with `fgets()` or `getline()` and then parse it out (Maybe with `sscanf()`. Much easier to recover from errors that way.

Comment: That's a step in the right direction. But you seem to believe that if scanf fails to match the format, it will somehow skip to where you want it to try the next call. It doesn't. It justs stops reading, so the next read operation will start with the first character not matched. (This is the only behaviour which makes sense, really. How would it know where to skip to?)

Comment: When you reach the end of input, `scanf` will return EOF.  EOF will evaluate as true, so your process enters an infinite loop.  You should consume the first line of input and discard it, and then do `while( 3 == scanf(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reading each line with getline(), then parsing it with either sscanf() or a custom parsing function.

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char   *linebuf = NULL;
    size_t  linemax = 0;
    ssize_t linelen;

    while (1) {
        char            type[2];
        unsigned long   addr;
        size_t          len;
        char            dummy;

        linelen = getline(&linebuf, &linemax, stdin);
        if (linelen == -1)
            break;

        if (sscanf(linebuf, "%1s %lx, %zu %c", type, &addr, &len, &dummy) == 3) {
            printf("type[0]=='%c', addr==0x%lx, len==%zu\n", type[0], addr, len);
        }
    }

    /* Optional: Discard used line buffer. Note: free(NULL) is safe. */
    free(linebuf);
    linebuf = NULL;
    linemax = 0;

    /* Check if getline() failed due to end-of-file, or due to an error. */
    if (!feof(stdin) || ferror(stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from standard input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Above, `linebuf` is a dynamically allocated buffer, and `linemax` the amount of memory allocated for it.  `getline()` has no line length limitations, other than available memory.

Because `%1s` (one-character token) is used to parse the first identifier letter, any whitespace before it is ignored.  (All conversions except `%c` and `%n` silently skip leading whitespace.)

The `%lx` converts the next token as a hexadecimal number into an `unsigned long` (which is exactly the same as `unsigned long int`).

The `%zu` converts the next token as a decimal nonnegative number into a `size_t`.

The final `%c` (converting to a `char`) is a dummy catcher; it isn't supposed to convert anything, but if it does, it means there was extra stuff on the line.  It is preceded by a space, because we intentionally want to skip whitespace after the conversion.

(A space in a scanf()/sscanf() conversion pattern means to skip any number of whitespace at that point, including *none*.)

The result from the scanf family of functions is the number of successful conversions.  So, if the line had the expected format, we get `3`.  (If there was extra stuff on the line, it will be `4`, since the dummy char converted something.)

This example program just prints out the values of `type[0]`, `addr`, and `len` as parsed, so you can easily replace it with whatever `if (type[0] == ...)` or `switch (type[0]) { ... }` logic you need.

Since the line buffer was allocated dynamically, it is a good practice to discard it.  We do need to initialize the buffer pointer to `NULL` and its size to `0`, so that `getline()` will allocate the initial buffer, but we don't necessarily *need* to free the buffer, since the OS will automatically free all memory used by the process.  That is why I added the comment about discarding the line buffer being optional.  (Fortunately, `free(NULL)` is safe to do and does nothing, so all we need to do is to `free(linebuf)`, and set `linebuf` to `NULL` and `linemax` to `0`, and we can even reuse the buffer.  Really, we can do that even just before a `getline()` totally safely.  So in that way, this is a very good example of how to do dynamic memory management: no line length limits!)

---

To *remember* each memory reference for some kind of processing, we really don't have to do much additional work:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct memref {
    size_t          addr;
    size_t          len;
    int             type;
};

struct memref_array {
    size_t          max;    /* Number of memory references allocated */
    size_t          num;    /* Number of memory references used */
    struct memref  *ref;    /* Dynamically allocated array of memory references */
};
#define MEMREF_ARRAY_INIT  { 0, 0, NULL }

static inline int  memref_array_add(struct memref_array *mra, size_t addr, size_t len, int type)
{
    /* Make sure we have a non-NULL pointer to a memref_array structure. */
    if (!mra)
        return -1;

    /* Make sure we have room for at least one more memref structure. */
    if (mra->num >= mra->max) {
        size_t          new_max;
        struct memref  *new_ref;

        /* Growth policy.  We need new_max to be at least mra->num + 1.
           Reallocation is "slow", so we want to allocate extra entries;
           but we don't want to allocate so much we waste oodles of memory.
           There are many possible allocation strategies, and which one is "best"
           -- really, most suited for a task at hand --, varies!
           This one uses a simple "always allocate 3999 extra entries" policy. */
        new_max = mra->num + 4000;

        new_ref = realloc(mra->ref, new_max * sizeof mra->ref[0]);
        if (!new_ref) {
            /* Reallocation failed.  Old data still exists, we just didn't get
               more memory for the new data.  This function just returns -2 to
               the caller; other options would be to print an error message and
               exit()/abort() the program. */
            return -2;
        }

        mra->max = new_max;
        mra->ref = new_ref;
    }

    /* Fill in the fields, */
    mra->ref[mra->num].addr = addr;
    mra->ref[mra->num].len  = len;
    mra->ref[mra->num].type = type;
    /* and update the number of memory references in the table. */
    mra->num++;

    /* This function returns 0 for success. */
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct memref_array  memrefs = MEMREF_ARRAY_INIT;

    char                *linebuf = NULL;
    size_t               linemax = 0;
    ssize_t              linelen;

    while (1) {
        char            type[2];
        unsigned long   addr;
        size_t          len;
        char            dummy;

        linelen = getline(&linebuf, &linemax, stdin);
        if (linelen == -1)
            break;

        if (sscanf(linebuf, "%1s %lx, %zu %c", type, &addr, &len, &dummy) == 3) {
            if (memref_array_add(&memrefs, (size_t)addr, len, type[0])) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory.\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Optional: Discard used line buffer. Note: free(NULL) is safe. */
    free(linebuf);
    linebuf = NULL;
    linemax = 0;

    /* Check if getline() failed due to end-of-file, or due to an error. */
    if (!feof(stdin) || ferror(stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from standard input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Print the number of entries stored. */
    printf("Read %zu memory references:\n", memrefs.num);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < memrefs.num; i++) {
        printf("    addr=0x%lx, len=%zu, type='%c'\n",
               (unsigned long)memrefs.ref[i].addr,
               memrefs.ref[i].len,
               memrefs.ref[i].type);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The new `memref` structure describes each memory reference we read, and the `memref_array` structure contains a dynamically allocated array of them.  The `num` member is the number of references in the array, and the `max` member is the number of references we have allocated memory for.

The `memref_array_add()` function takes a pointer to a `memref_array`, and the three values to fill in.  Because C passes function parameters by value – that is, changing a parameter value in a function does not change the variable in the caller! – we need to pass a pointer, so that making the changes via the pointer, the changes are visible in the caller too.  This is just how C works.

In that function, we need to take care of the memory management ourselves.  Because we use the `MEMREF_ARRAY_INIT` to initialize the memory reference array to known safe values, we can use `realloc()` to resize the array pointer whenever needed.  (Essentially, `realloc(NULL, size)` works exactly the same as `malloc(size)`.)

In the main program, we call that function in an if clause.  `if (x)` is the same as `if (x != 0)`, ie. the body is executed if `x` is nonzero.  Because the `memref_array_add()` returns zero if success, and nonzero if error, `if (memref_array_add(...))` means *"if memref_array_add call fails, then"*.

Note that we don't discard the memory reference array in the program at all.  We don't *need to*, because the OS will free it for us.  But, if the program did do further work after no longer needing the memory reference array, then it would make sense to discard it.  I bet you guessed that this is just as simple as discarding the line buffer used by `getline()`:

```c
static inline void memref_array_free(struct memref_array *mra)
{
    if (mra) {
        free(mra->ref);
        mra->max = 0;
        mra->num = 0;
        mra->ref = NULL;
    }
}
```

so that in the main program, `memref_array_free(&memrefs);` would suffice.

The `static inline` in front of the function definitions just tells the compiler to inline the functions at their call sites, and not produce linkable symbols for them.  You can omit them if you like; I use them to indicate that these are helper functions usable only in this file (or compilation unit).

The reason we use `memrefs.member` in the main program, but `mra->member` in the helper functions, is that `mra` is a pointer to the structure, whereas `memrefs` is a variable of the structure type.  Again, just a C quirk.  (We could write `(&memrefs)->member`, or `(*mra).member`, just as well.)

This is probably much more than you wanted to read (not just OP, but *you*, dear reader), but I've always felt that dynamic memory management should be shown as early as possible to new C programmers, so that they grasp them with confidence, instead of seeing it as difficult/not worth it.